# Asp.Net Web Api token authentication in Angular 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, entity-framework, oauth-2.0

is there any documentation how to implement Asp.Net Web Api(oauth2 ) token authentication in Angular 5 ?  i can use it with postman and consume the bearer token key ... but i do not know how to use it with angular 5 and there is no documentation or examples to learn from .

Comment: I have Same problem....